# How to copy a folder with resources using Premake5

Tags: c++, build, project, premake

**Question No. 1**

The root folder looks something like this:

```
    <project-dir> 
    ├─build
    │ └─bin
    │   └─Debug
    │     ├─data
    │     │ └─player.png
    │     └─game.exe
    ├─data
    │ └─sprites
    │   └─player.png
    ├─src
    │ └─main.cpp
    └─premake5.lua
```

When trying to copy the `data` folder to the `build/bin/Debug/` folder using the command:

```
postbuildcommands "{COPYDIR} data \"build/bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}\" /s /h /e /k /f /c"
```

This error pops up:

```
error MSB3073: command error "xcopy /Q /E /Y /I data "build\bin\Debug" \s \h \e \k \f \c
error MSB3073: :VCEnd" with code 4.
```

**Question No. 2**

There are 2 options:

1. I'll point the path directly from main.cpp (`LoadFromFile("../data/sprites/player.png");`)
2. I will specify the path this way (`LoadFromFile("data/sprites/player/png);`)

In the first variant, the code runs in Visual Studio, but if you run `.exe`, the file will not be found, in addition, if the source file is nested many times, you will have to write `../../../`.

In the second option, Visual Studio cannot download the file, but the `.exe` file that is being run will open it successfully.

How can I get rid of this problem?

I tried to use different syntax variants of the `{COPYDIR}` command, but nothing happened. And how to solve the problem described in the second question, I can't even imagine.

Comment: For the second problem, paths are relative to working directory.  it can be set via IDE when launching the program (I think by default it is the path where solution resides) (I guess from *build* directory (and `"../data"` would refer to same directory from *src* or *build* directory)).

Comment: One question by question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of `{COPYDIR}` is to be generic, and those extra flags only make sense for `xcopy` (not unix `cp`).

And unfortunately, in:

```lua
postbuildcommands "{COPYDIR} data \"build/bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}\" /s /h /e /k /f /c"
```

All flags `/s` `/h` `/e` `/k` `/f` and `/c` are considered as paths, and Premake *"normalizes"* them (so for windows with `\` separator) :-(

As possible workarounds:

- drop those extra flags if possible
- create a script which forward to xcopy with given flags.
- use [`buildaction`](https://premake.github.io/docs/buildaction/):

  ```lua
  filter "files:data/**"
      buildaction ("Copy")
  ```

  but directories risk to be flattened.